how to refresh child listview programatically
There are 2 lists. Parent and Child list.
when the item on parent is clicked, the child list needs to be refreshed. This is not working on the sample.
When the list item on parent is clicked, nothing is changing in the child. the data is populated but is not refreshed visually

// code is uploaded in https://share.linqpad.net/9qrb7wje.linq

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;


void Main()
{
    // Sample Data (replace with your database queries)
    var table1 = new List<ParentRow>
    {
        new ParentRow { ParentID = 1, ParentName = "Parent 1" },
        new ParentRow { ParentID = 2, ParentName = "Parent 2" },
        new ParentRow { ParentID = 3, ParentName = "Parent 3" }
    };

    var table2 = new List<ChildRow>
    {
        new ChildRow { ChildID = 1, ParentID = 1, ChildName = "Child 1.1" },
        new ChildRow { ChildID = 2, ParentID = 1, ChildName = "Child 1.2" },
        new ChildRow { ChildID = 3, ParentID = 2, ChildName = "Child 2.1" }
    };

    // Create Windows Forms
    var form = new Form { Text = "Drill Through Example", Width = 800, Height = 600 };

    // Table 1 ListView (Parent Table)
    var listView1 = new ListView { View = View.Details, Dock = DockStyle.Left, Width = 300 };
    listView1.Columns.Add("ParentID", 80);
    listView1.Columns.Add("ParentName", 200);

    foreach (var row in table1)
    {
        var item = new ListViewItem(row.ParentID.ToString());
        item.SubItems.Add(row.ParentName);
        item.Tag = row.ParentID; // Store ParentID in Tag for reference
        listView1.Items.Add(item);
    }

    // Table 2 ListView (Child Table)
    var listView2 = new ListView { View = View.Details, Dock = DockStyle.Fill };
    listView2.Columns.Add("ChildID", 80);
    listView2.Columns.Add("ChildName", 200);

    // Event to Handle Drill Through
    listView1.SelectedIndexChanged += (sender, args) =>
    {
        if (listView1.SelectedItems.Count > 0) // Ensure an item is selected
        {
            var selectedParentID = (int)listView1.SelectedItems[0].Tag; // Retrieve ParentID from Tag
            var childRows = table2.Where(c => c.ParentID == selectedParentID).ToList(); // Filter child rows

            // Clear and update child ListView
            listView2.BeginUpdate(); // Pause UI updates for performance
            listView2.Items.Clear();
            foreach (var child in childRows)
            {
                var item = new ListViewItem(child.ChildID.ToString());
                item.SubItems.Add(child.ChildName);
                listView2.Items.Add(item);
            }
            listView2.EndUpdate(); // Resume UI updates
            listView2.Refresh(); // Force visual refresh
        }
    };

    // Add Controls to Form
    form.Controls.Add(listView1);
    form.Controls.Add(listView2);

    // Show Form
    form.ShowDialog();
}

// Define Classes for Parent and Child Rows
public class ParentRow
{
    public int ParentID { get; set; }
    public string ParentName { get; set; }
}

public class ChildRow
{
    public int ChildID { get; set; }
    public int ParentID { get; set; }
    public string ChildName { get; set; }
}



Change your listView2's DockStyle.Fill to DockStyle.Bottom and re-run your code. It should work.

thanks. it works. can you help me understand the difference?

It's just that listView2's content isn't visible because it's hidden in the top left-hand corner behind listview1.

listview2 uses DockStyle.Fill which fills the entire parent form container. Meanwhile listview1 fills the left side. Combining these two things makes listview2 left area which uses to display items is invisible.
